# What is the purpose of both brahmana bojanam and pinda pradanam in shraddha

Tags: death, pitru, sraddha

I have a curious question on shraddha ceremony we perform, during shraddha we invite brahmins for brahmana bhojanam as per ritual we invoke our pitrus(vasu, rudra and aditya) on body of brahmins and serve food for them and these pitru devatas are responsible for giving these food to our forfathers in whatever form they are.

At a same time we also perform pinda pradanam for forefathers, what is the purpose of both? If pitru devatas which we invoked on brahmins takes care of giving food to our forefathers why do we again require pinda pradnam? Isn't it one enough (either brahmin bhojanam or pinda pradanam).

Can anyone shed light on this? If question is unclear, I can happily edit it.